# How to fetch words from text with regex in Swift iOS?

Tags: regex, swift

I have as string:

```
let inputText:String = "myemail_at_gmail.com_organizer@company.com"
```

I want to get in output: `myemail@gmail.com`

So I need to write 1st some pattern that matches this rule:

`<email_prefix>`*_at_*`<domain>_`*organizer@company.com*

after that I can combine:

`<email_prefix>`*@*`<domain>`

I use following class:

```
class Regex {
    let internalExpression: NSRegularExpression
    let pattern: String

    init(_ pattern: String) {
        self.pattern = pattern
        var error: NSError?
        self.internalExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)!
    }

    func test(input: String) -> Bool {
        let matches = self.internalExpression.matchesInString(input, options: nil, range:NSMakeRange(0, count(input)))
        return matches.count > 0
    }
}
```

and look for regex syntax:

```
if Regex("^\\w+_at_\\w+_organizer@company.com$") // id doesn't work
    .test(inputText) {

   let result:String = inputText.split("_at_")[0] + "@" + inputText.split("_at_")[1].split("_organizer@company.com")[0]

}
```

This one doesn't work: `"^\\w+_at_\\w+_organizer@company.com$"`

This one works but its not completed: `"\\w+_organizer@company.com$"`

Please help,

Comment: "." is a special character. So you may have issue.

Comment: `email_prefix` is email without domain

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution:

since i work with email, i need validate email name and email domain separatly:

```
let inputText:String = "myemail_at_gmail.com_organizer@company.com"

    if Regex("^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+_at_[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}_organizer@company.com$")
    .test(inputText) {


        let result:String = inputText.split("_at_")[0] + "@" +
                        inputText.split("_at_")[1].split("_organizer@company.com")[0]
        print(result) // myemail@gmail.com
}
```

Comment: maybe someone will write better solution